# Not able to Scrape from individual "embeded" links - receive the following error message a "SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Used a similar code structure to scrape other sites.
But appear to have an issue with gaining access to the links.

Solved it for the webpage URL with the first line of code.
However, when I try to retrieve data from specific company sites, I get SLL error.
I tried incorporating the code used for the webpage URL but didn't manage.

Is there a work around?

```
webpage <- "https://fsncapital.com/en/investments/investments-divestments/"
page <- webpage %>% 
  httr::GET(config = httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE)) %>% 
  read_html()

## Retrieve the embedded linked

Comp_Links = page %>% html_nodes(".investments-grid .name") %>%
  html_attr("href")

## get company name
get_ownership =function(comp_link) {
  comp_page = read_html(comp_link)
  ownership = comp_page %>% html_node("p:nth-child(4)") %>%
    html_text()
  return(ownership)
}

Ownership = sapply(Comp_Links, FUN = get_ownership)
```

Comment: I don't get such error/message. When I run your code I get values as `"FSN Ownership 68%"`, `"FSN Ownership 77%"` etc in `Ownership`. Are you behind a firewall ?

Comment: me too. The script returns FSN Ownership 68%, ...., FSN Ownership 99.72% and so on.

Comment: really weird, tried it again. But still, get the same error message  "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired " don't think I am behind a firewall. Is there somewhere I can see if i am using a firewall? Or could it be that I am using a mac